# jQuery sending out multiple of the same ajax calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

From C# I am returning this way

```
return PartialView("~/View.cshtml", model);
```

In view, I am updating the data this way. After binding this way I am getting request multiple times.

```
$("#LoanCommitteDateSubmitedselected").change(function ()
{
    $.ajax({
        success: function (data)
        {
            $("#sectionName").html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

After doing this in Ajax form submit I am getting request multiple times in below method.

```
$('#sectionName').submit(function (e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        success: function (response)
        {
        }
    });
});
```

Can Anyone advise me how to resolve this issue?

Comment: hey can you please share your code.

Comment: where is this `submit` function is written? is it within same `html` that you put after ajax success?

Comment: this is a bad approach '.change' you need to be more specific about the action you are using.

Answer (score 0):

That might be a problem with multiple event registration.

You can try unbinding and then binding your submit function as-

```
$('#sectionName').off('submit');
$('#sectionName').on('submit',function (e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        success: function (response)
        {
        }
    });
});
```